# Network calls take more time on iOS than on Android

Tags: ios

I have a very strange problem, in Android, the API calls take 300-500 ms while in iOS it takes 1.5-2.5 sec. I have removed dependencies like my server, device specific issue, internet connectivity etc. I have a very simple sample code hitting a sample URL and for me, it takes about 2 sec, even on the simulator.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"start");

    // 1
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://httpbin.org/get"];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

    // 2
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"GET";

    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                    // Handle response here
                    NSLog(@"end - %ld", (long)[(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode]);
                }] resume];
});
```

I also have tried using AFNetworking and ASSIHTTP libraries, but there is no difference. I also have checked the headers and they are the same in both Android and iOS. What am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code with single API but it still it takes 1.62 secs, Checked in server the response time shows 500 ms only. Any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is not in the network but in this line: 
`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{`

Can you remove it and check again?

Data task is async so you don't need to wrap it in another async block.

Also you don't need to create instance of `NSURLSession` for every request

Comment: The only thing that has improved the response time is using the same NSURLSession object. Can I reuse the same NSURLSession for multiple simulatneous calls? I doubt it wont be allowed.

Comment: Yes, you can. It is absolutely okay to reuse session till you make requests  to the same host. In other words one session one host.

Comment: Seems like this was the issue, I had to reused NSURLSession for all calls to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @sage444 , I have tried as you said with single API but it still it takes 1.62 secs, Checked in server the response time shows 500 ms only. Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can log out the timestamp (NSLog already did) when the request generate, send, callback to analyse it.

Answer (score 0):

Does the server side code do any processing based on 'user-agent'? 
Is there a time difference if you open the url in iOS safari and within the app ?

You can try calling the api from postman (or another REST API test tool like firefox RESTClient) and override the user-agent to use iOS values (http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/UserAgent). If the time difference is still the same, theres nothing you can do in your mobile code to fix this lag.

P.S. : 
1. Overriding user-agent in postman needs some tweaking : https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/wiki/Postman-Proxy